# How to pull updates from a specific branch using git

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am not an expert in git.

I have coded the following:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python Yamed> git branch
  explore
* master
```

I would like to pull the updates from the `branch`  `explore`

I tried `git pull` but this is the message i get:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> master
```

I also tried

```
git pull origin explore
```

but i get an error as follows:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python Yamed> git pull origin explore
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Some information that might be helpful:

PS C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Python Yamed> git remote -v

```
YakeeyData      https://github.com/yakeey/yk-estimate.git (fetch)
YakeeyData      https://github.com/yakeey/yk-estimate.git (push)
Yakeey_Data     https://github.com/yakeey/yk-estimate.git (fetch)
Yakeey_Data     https://github.com/yakeey/yk-estimate.git (push)
```

Comment: Hello, please share the result of the `git remote -v` command. It allows to get the information about the remote repo you point to.

Comment: Please see answer in the original question thank you

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, so in your case, there is no `origin` remote, it seems to be called `YakeeyData` instead, so you just need to do a `git pull YakeeyData explore`

Comment: Can't see the arrow to upvote ..I created another account and I lost the privilege to upvote

Comment: Oh no need to worry, thanks anyway  
I'll put an answer directly with more detailed explanation, it will be more clear if someone else looks for it. You can accept it if it seems relevant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP's question is tagged with "Visual Studio", it's worth noting in addition to the [answer of Fares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74000282/10871073), that Visual Studio 2022 doesn't allow fetching non local branches from a remote named something other than `origin` when right-clicking on *remote branches* in the interface.

However, if you wish to fetch / push refs with a local branch to a remote that is named differently than `origin`, then you have to set your remote tracking branch first. Therefore, you'd have to do the following:

```
> git fetch YakeeyData explore
> git branch -u YakeeyData/explore explore
```

That would make sure that `explore` is tracking `YakeeyData/explore`. Then, in Visual Studio 2022, you could right-click the **local branch** `explore` to fetch/push from/to remote `YakeeyData`.

Answer (score 0):

Using git, you can add as many upstream repo address you want with git remote add (from "[Git Basics - Working with Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)").

In your case, there is no upstream repo called `origin`.
It seems to be called `YakeeyData` instead.

So you just need to do a `git pull YakeeyData explore`

Underneath, this command will result in the following two commands

```
git fetch YakeeyData explore && git merge explore
```